# How to get the maximum count of data in string format

Tags: r, database, dataframe, max

**This is my code:**

```
   table(Car_DataSet_no_na$Dealer)
```

**Output:**

```
> table(Car_DataSet_no_na$Dealer)
 
  Anny David Henry 
  870   263   128
```

**I assigned it as (x) and want to to get the maximum Dealer:**

```
> x<-table(Car_DataSet_no_na$Dealer)
> max(x)
[1] 870
```

**It gives me only the number,How can I get the number and name of the Dealer?**

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Try `which.max(x)`?

Comment: `tail(sort(x), 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain the answer of Adam Quek in a reproducible example:

```
exampleVector <- sample(x = rep(x = c("Pikachu", "Charmander", "Balbasaur"), 
                                times = c(30, 15, 45)))

x <- table(exampleVector)

# The number
max(x)

# The name
names(x)[which.max(x)]
```

Is it what you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `max(x)` for showing the number and use the `example<- which.max(x)` to show the string format or (name).